# CodeIgniter xss_clean issue with large amount of html [in firefox]

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, google-chrome, firefox

I'm receiving the following error on console:

```
<p>Severity: 8192</p>
<p>Message:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead</p>
<p>Filename: core/Security.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 512</p>
```

Which refers to the function in Core/Security line 512:

```
public function entity_decode($str, $charset='UTF-8'){
    if (stristr($str, '&') === FALSE)
    {
        return $str;
    }

    $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, $charset);
    $str = preg_replace('~&#x(0*[0-9a-f]{2,5})~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $str);
    return preg_replace('~&#([0-9]{2,4})~e', 'chr(\\1)', $str);
}
```

This happens because I'm inserting large amount of HTML (pure HTML) into the Database.

```
public function add($data){
    $this->security->xss_clean($data);
    $this->db->insert('covers', $data);

    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

If I remove the line `$this->security->xss_clean($data);` it works perfectly.

A curious thing is that it works on Chrome but it stops working on Chrome as soon as I test it on Firefox (v. 32.0.1). After testing in Firefox and receiving the error if I go to Chrome and test again I have the same issue in Chrome too.

**Edit**: Even with this error, and even with the line `$this->security->xss_clean($data);` on, the information is stored in database but the warning is displayed in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I went to Ellislab support and they told me that the function is no longer in use.
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20646/the-e-modifier-is-deprecated-use-preg_replace_callback-instead

I copy the new `core/Security.php` and paste on mine and it's now working.

Comment: Please can you share the function from that file please? Link is broken.

Comment: @AlphaMale https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php search for `entity_decode`

Comment: Error changed to: 
Message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 171061

Answer (score 0):

use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);` in your code this will suppress the error

Comment: Well, I would like not to supress the issue, but find a way to use that function `preg_replace_callback`.